# Vocabulary: Functions whose values would not change if the variables were interchanged

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, terminology

Consider the function

$$f(x,y,z):= \sqrt{1+x^2+y^2+z^2}.$$

Then $f(x,y,z) = f(x,z,y) = \cdots = f(z,y,x)$

Do functions such as $f,$ whose values would not change for any possible permutation of the variables, have a specific name? I only care because it seems convenient to be able to refer to these functions by a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do functions such as $f,$ whose values would not change for any possible permutation of the variables, have a specific name?

They are called [symmetric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function).

Comment: It's worth noting that a function such as $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{1+2x^2+2y^2+z^2}$ that isn't "fully" symmetric can be described as "symmetric in $x$ and $y$".

Comment: @Blue thank you!